# Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.twitter:util-core

Tags: scala, sbt

I upgraded to sbt 0.13 and this issue started to pop out.
I've found explaination here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/MoApqIwx4R0

I'm still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the conflict by setting:

```
conflictWarning := ConflictWarning.disable,
```

It might be possible to resolve the conflict by configuring the conflict manager. SBT 0.13's conflict management is described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#conflict-management). If you want one of the [predefined conflict managers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/conflict-managers.html), they are defined in the ConflictManager object:

```
object ConflictManager {
    val all = ConflictManager("all")
    val latestTime = ConflictManager("latest-time")
    val latestRevision = ConflictManager("latest-revision")
    val latestCompatible = ConflictManager("latest-compatible")
    val strict = ConflictManager("strict")
    val default = latestRevision
}
```

For example, to select the latest version (by revision string), you would add the following to your project's settings:

```
conflictManager := ConflictManager.latestRevision
```

Comment: From the linked thread in the original question: "Due to the limitations of the pom format, it is not possible to handle [cross-version conflicts] in the normal resolution phase, where it could be properly resolved with error in favor of the `_2.10` variants.  Instead, sbt checks after resolution and gives an error, which is better than having duplicates on the classpath."