# Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm

Tags: build, playframework, sbt

At my end, I have the following setup

C:>where play
C:\apps\play-2.2.0\play
C:\apps\play-2.2.0\play.bat

C:>where scala
C:\apps\scala\bin\scala
C:\apps\scala\bin\scala.bat

---

Scala -version > Scala code runner version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Play - version >

play 2.2.0 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_21), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.

---

When I run at my play prompt > reload, update, I get following error

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in     {file:/C:/<filepat>}<appname>:
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.10, _2.10.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Oct 18, 2013 1:33:41 PM
[modelingApp] $
```

After adding the follwoing in Build.scala

```
"dependencyGroupId"         %% "dependencyArtifactId" % "dependencyVersion"    exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")
```

Get following error

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:       dependencyGroupId#dependencyArtifactId_2.10;dependencyVersion: not found
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed Oct 18, 2013 1:22:18 PM
[modelingApp] $
```

Comment: Tried to add >>> "com.typesafe.play"         %% "play-slick"     % "0.5.0.2-SNAPSHOT" in build.scala as appDependencies but no luck either.

Comment: Please post your entire build.sbt file. "dependencyGroupId" etc. is just a pseudo name for a not existing library to show which parts need ed to resolve a dependency, so of course it could not be found.

Comment: Since it is play app, it does not have build.sbt

Comment: Since Play 2.2.0 it has no project/Build.scala anymore but a build.sbt. Do you use a project with a previous Play version with the current Play version?

Comment: added >>> (at the end of the dependency which was being loaded from other project and it worked >>>>) exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")

Comment: @Schleichardt - with this problem, we have 3 projects (playApp1, sbtApp1, sbtLib). playApp1 and sbtApp1's build.sbt and Build.scala files, respectively, include a dependency on the sbtLib library. Should we exclude the offending libraries (Scala STM) in sbtLib **or** sbtApp1 and playApp1? Also, it's a Play 2.1 app that was **migrated** to Play 2.2 using these notes - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue on Play:

[Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-stm:scala-stm](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1467)

[Maybe you use play slick that is not ready for Play 2.2.](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/72)

Try

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

Or if it is another lib that has a dependency to Play 2.1.x, try

```
//replace the name and versions with that of your library
//since Scala 2.10.0 do not put the minor version into the artifact name:
//scala-stm_2.10 instead of scala-stm_2.10.0
"the lib vendor" %% "name" % "version" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0")
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the *only* means of detecting scala version mismatch in sbt is via this artifact extension "_".

This particular issue is that the version of scala-stm that Play is depending on is declaring it is *ONLY* compatible with scala 2.10.0, whereas your build says it can take anything from the 2.10.x series.   sbt is issuing a warning that these are different.

In practice, the scala-stm artifact is actually safe to use, it's just misconfigured on publish (documentation error at the time I believe).  So in this case, it's safe to ignore the error.  however, in general, this error should be taken seriously.  It's very possible that different Scala binary version numbers declared on artifacts may lead to RUNTIME errors (not compile time) that insidiously sneak into your code.

You can use the `conflictWarning` key to control how this message is logged.   I believe if you want to ignore the warnings completely (not recommended, as most should be legitimiate issues), then you can use this setting:

```
conflictWarning := ConflictWarning.disable
```

Also, I believe this is a duplicate of this question: [Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.twitter:util-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153818/conflicting-cross-version-suffixes-in-com-twitterutil-core)

Comment: That's not a terribly helpful answer.  While it may be safe to ignore the error, a pointer to some concrete steps to make it *possible* to ignore the error would be helpful...

Comment: Hmm, tried to edit the response.   THe way to disable is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153818/conflicting-cross-version-suffixes-in-com-twitterutil-core

I do not recommend turning them off completely as most errors will be valid issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when upgrading from Play 2.1.* to Play 2.2.*.   The project included secureSocial which also needed to be updated to Play 2.2.

```
"securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.0"
```

to

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3"
```

See [Secure Social Installation Documentation](http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depend on your scala version, for example i use:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.11" % "2.3.6"
```

for scala 2.11.1.
You can find appropriate version from [this link](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/akka/).